# Can I sort the contents by stat from the facebook like button?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

Is that possible?sould I combine the like number into mysql?

Comment: can you give more information on how you are wanting to sort it?  Are you using the JS sdk or the FBML?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you have a set of pages and you want to sort links to them according to their like counters. You can do this using FQL:

```
SELECT url, like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url IN("FIRST_URL","SECOND_URL") ORDER BY like_count desc
```

(see [`link_stat`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat) table)

Comment: select post_id from link_stat

Comment: then I can query mysql by post_id get content detail.

Comment: @nzh If you want to sort posts then you can run FQL on `stream` table to get like counts for posts.